# Datatable case-insensitive sorting

Tags: sorting, datatables

I am using datatable and want to sorting/ordering some column (in my case it is first column) like this:

```
A
a
B
b
C
c
```

instead of

```
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

I have the following code:

```
/* Define two custom functions (asc and desc) for string sorting */
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

and in datatable script I have:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tpl-table').DataTable({

"aoColumns": [
        { "sType": 'string-case' },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
});
```

When code runs, having the following error as in below pic

[image]

I have 5 columns in a datatable and want to sort first column.
Anyone can help out..

Comment: Does the ordering of `A` before `a` really matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter...A comes after a

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
var data = [{
    "letter": "A"
}, {
    "letter": "a"
}, {
    "letter": "B"
}, {
    "letter": "b"
}, {
    "letter": "C"
}, {
    "letter": "c"
}];

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "lower-letter-pre": function(a) {
        return a.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);
    },
    "lower-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "lower-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});


$(function() {
    var example = $("#example").DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
            {
                "title": "Letter",
                "type": "lower-letter",
                "data": "letter"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/2fuoa9og/). I guess you could take a reference to the original character and if it's lower case add 0.5 to ensure consistent ordering for upper case and lower case characters...? Hope that helps.

Comment: OK..I will try it and inform you

Comment: The code is working fine...data is coming from front side here..In my case it is coming from server side...Anyway...it helps